# Why use IEnumerable<T> when we can Iterate through collection using foreach()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, ienumerable

I want to know the exact place where we should use `IEnumberable<T>`

I know how `IEnumerable<T>` work and returns `IEnumerator<T>` and all that but the ultimate goal of `IEnumerable<T>` is to query the data from the collection isn't it? That is what we can already do using foreach() loop ? So when to use `IEnumerable<T>`? what is the actual practical scenario where the `IEnumerable<T>` is the only option to query the collection?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to ask. A `foreach` loop can loop over anything which implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: The point of `IEnumberale<T>` isn't to "query a collection". The point is to represent any collection which can be iterated over. So anything which can be iterated over should implement `IEnumerable<T>`, and that way you can use a `foreach` loop to loop over it

Comment: I'm not sure what misunderstanding you have here, but unless you only iterate over arrays, `foreach` ***needs*** the type you are iterating over to implement `IEnumerable<T>` to work.

Comment: I can loop on a collection using foreach() directly - so when to use IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: @HammadMaqbool You can only iterate over the collection *because* it implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @canton7 /s/collection/sequence

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, and I've said a bunch of other things which aren't strictly true as well. Trying to be clear rather than completely correct, since the problem here is a conceptual misunderstanding rather than a problem with the details

Comment: @HammadMaqbool when you use foreach, you use IEnumerable<T>. Like others above said, the foreach keyword makes use of IEnumerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but the ultimate goal of `IEnumerable<T>` is to query the data from the collection isn't it?

No; the goal of `IEnumerable<T>` is to provide access to a *sequence*, which may or may not be a collection. The point being to *abstract away* what the underlying source is. It *could* be a raw collection, but it could be:

- some LINQ (or similar) projection (`collection.Where(...).Select(...)` etc)
- an open query to ADO.NET, redis, a socket, gRPC, a file or some other data provider that *isn't* readily countable, repeatable, etc - just: "a sequence"
- an in-process data generator
- some producer/consumer setup
- etc

If you know you're always iterating a collection, then sure: feel free to use the concrete type, or `ICollection<T>`/`IList<T>` etc; but: not every sequence is a collection.